# How to take constraints into account while creating a REST-Client with openApi Generator

Tags: axios, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a spring-boot REST-Server. I use springdoc-openapi to generate my openapi-description.
Based on the description, I want to generate a typescript/axios client using the openapi-generator. It works fine, but i have one problem: the constraints are not taken into consideration.

Here an exemple of a DTO as specified in the openapi-description.yaml

```
AuftraggeberDTO:
  required:
    - anschrift
    - anzahlNiederlassungen
    - kontaktpersonFuerZulassungsstelle
    - organisationsname
    - validUntil
  type: object
  properties:
    organisationsname:
      maxLength: 1024
      minLength: 0
      type: string
    anschrift:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/AnschriftDTO'
    telefonnummer:
      maxLength: 1024
      minLength: 0
      type: string
    kontaktpersonFuerZulassungsstelle:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/KontaktpersonDTO'
    validUntil:
      type: string
      format: date-time
    anzahlNiederlassungen:
      type: integer
      format: int32
```

And now the Typescript-DTO that has been generated:

```
    export interface AuftraggeberDTO {
  /**
   *
   * @type {string}
   * @memberof AuftraggeberDTO
   */
  'organisationsname': string;
  /**
   *
   * @type {AnschriftDTO}
   * @memberof AuftraggeberDTO
   */
  'anschrift': AnschriftDTO;
  /**
   *
   * @type {string}
   * @memberof AuftraggeberDTO
   */
  'telefonnummer'?: string;
  /**
   *
   * @type {KontaktpersonDTO}
   * @memberof AuftraggeberDTO
   */
  'kontaktpersonFuerZulassungsstelle': KontaktpersonDTO;
  /**
   *
   * @type {string}
   * @memberof AuftraggeberDTO
   */
  'validUntil': string;
  /**
   *
   * @type {number}
   * @memberof AuftraggeberDTO
   */
  'anzahlNiederlassungen': number;
}
```

See, the validation is gone.
How can i solve that ?

As additional info:
I generated the client using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api-description.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>typescript-axios</generatorName>
                        <output>./../vue-client/generated-client/typescript-axios</output>
                        <apiPackage>com.example.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.example.model</modelPackage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the typescript generators don't support validations yet. (source: [searching](https://github.com/search?q=path%3A*.mustache+maxLength+repo%3AOpenAPITools%2Fopenapi-generator++NOT+path%3A%2Fpython%2F+NOT+path%3A%2Faspnet%2F++NOT+path%3A%2F%5CWphp%5CW%2F+NOT+path%3A%2F%5CWJava%5CW%2F&type=code&p=1) the code of OpenAPI Generator)

There is a related feature request [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/8024).

So for the time being you could add the validation manually to the generated code, and/or open a Pull Request in the OpenAPI Generator project.